# Lookup a cells in one worksheet and return value into another work sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in one worksheet showing order no. with items and qty
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvy9n.jpg)

In another work sheet I would like to enter the order number and all the items and quantities for that then order number are displayed. hope it makes sense.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And you can read here on how to ask a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to do a Google search for "how to create a pivot table", then try it and if you have problems ask a specific question about the problem you are encountering. Here is one [link](https://www.excelcampus.com/pivot-tables/pivot-tables-work/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether you need a list or a sum at the other sheet but if it is the SUM then below solution would work for you. If you need a list then most probably a VBA solution will be needed.

Assuming that your data is on `Sheet1` and at `Cols A to C`:

Write below formula to `B1` on `Sheet2` and copy down. When you write an Item code to `Col:A`, the total calculated of that Item will be shown at `Col:B`

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C;Sheet1!B:B;Sheet2!A1)
```